# How to stop μTorrent from eating all the memory?

Tags: memory, bittorrent, cache, utorrent

When I'm seeding with μTorrent (usually 100+ torrents), the memory usage is slowly crawling up (8GB RAM). Just two or three hours seeding and it's maxed out. I looked into this with Windows performance monitor and the value I was curious about is called "Memory/Cache bytes".
How do I stop this one from going through the roof?

The newer versions are all doing this (since this summer). Whatever I do with disk cache options, it has no effect.
I'm using an old 2.x release now, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

μTorrent will put cache files into memory by default, this is to reduce access to hard disk to increase performance. You can disable cache and μTorrent will then read files from hard disk every time, but the speed difference between RAM and hard disk is very large. Since you are seeding so many files, you should add more RAM to your system, after all, there isn't much a software can do for hardware limitations.

For your second question, here are official explanations from [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958286.aspx):

> Memory \ Cache Bytes    Monitor this counter for growth or shrinkage of the cache. The value includes not only the size of the cache but also the size of the paged pool and the amount of pageable driver and kernel code. Essentially, these values measure the systems working set.

Comment: AFAIK there is no option do disable OS cache in the latest versions of μTorrent, just the own cache of the application. I disabled / limited the cache of the application, and its still maxing out RAM.